# Pageable treeview using Kendo?

Tags: kendo-ui

Let's say I have hierarchical data that I display in a treeview. It's possible that a particular node might have 1000 children and I don't want to display them all, so I'm toying with the idea of paging the nodes in a tree. I would show 10 children and if there are more, the user needs to click on the next/previous buttons to see them. I've got sql paging working but I can't get the treeview to do what I want.

If I do this, my controller gets the proper node id and page id and it returns the correct page of results back. But then the treeview shows only the 1 page of children I just requested; the rest of the hierarchy (all the parents) is lost:

```
$("#btnNextPage")
    .click(function () {
        var selectedNode = treeview.select();
        var selectedNodeID = treeview.dataItem(selectedNode).id;
        ds.read({
            LoopID: selectedNodeID,
            page: ds.page() + 1
});
```

If I do this, I can keep the hierarchy and my controller gets called, but I can't figure out how to pass in the page that I'm requesting.

```
$("#btnNextPage")
    .click(function () {
        var selectedNode = treeview.select();
        var testnode = treeview.dataItem(selectedNode);
        testnode.loaded(false);
        testnode.load();
});
```

I've been using ASP.NET webforms and this is my first foray into jquery and kendo. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a pointer from the folks at Telerik, I got this working. The trick was to use the children property which is the datasource for the children of the selected node. So when the next page button is clicked I do this:

`parentNodeDataItem.children.read({
            LoopID: parentNodeID,
            page: currentPage
        });`

This produced the behavior I wanted, which was for the children to be refreshed without losing the ancestor hierarchy.

Comment: can you provide code for front end and controller code? i need to implement same in mvc application

Answer (score 0):

When you change pages the Kendo DataSource replaces its records in memory with the new page retrieved from the server.

You would need to retain all the previously loaded pages in a separate observable array and bind your treeview to that instead.

Comment: Example please? I'm still not clear how to proceed from here.